# Populate random number in a img src

Tags: javascript, html, image, pixel, tagging

I've been asked to insert a CACHEBUSTER (random number) within this third party pixel below:

```
<img src='http://yourdomain.com?dfew&chpcm=&chpsg=&chpcr=&chpck=&rand=INSERT_CACHEBUSTER&chpth=' width='1' height='1' border='0'>
```

The random number is supposed to populate in the rand URL parameter, but I do not know how to go about doing this.

Comment: Can you change that HTML?

Comment: Why do this with JavaScript? Remove your dependency on the client having JavaScript enabled and just add the random number when the HTML is generated (server-side)

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the 'INSERT_CACHEBUSTER' with a timestamp, like this:

```
var img = document.querySelector('img[src*="INSERT_CACHEBUSTER"]')
img.src = img.src.replace('INSERT_CACHEBUSTER', (new Date()).getTime())
```

Timestamp works better than a random number because it increments every millisecond, so there's virtually no way for it to repeat which would the case with a random number, but if you really want random:

```
img.src = img.src.replace('INSERT_CACHEBUSTER', Math.random())
```

EDIT: both solutions make it possible to hit the tracking server twice: once with the placeholder string then once again after the `src` is modfied. You can avoid it by either using another attribute, for example `data-src`:

```
// HTML
<img data-src='http://blahblah&rand=INSERT_CACHEBUSTER' width='1' height='1' border='0'>

// JS
var img = document.querySelector('img[data-src*="INSERT_CACHEBUSTER"]')
img.src = img.getAttribute('data-src').replace('INSERT_CACHEBUSTER', (new Date()).getTime());
```

or generating the tracking image in pure JS

```
var img = new Image();
img.width = 1;
img.height = 1;
img.src = 'http://h.nexac.com/e/a-858/s-1486/c-705/g-2423.xgi?pkey=xbue89gtzpg16&chpcm=&chpsg=&chpcr=&chpck=&rand=' + (new Date()).getTime() +'&chpth=';
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var image = document.querySelector('#pixel-img');
image.src = 'http://h.nexac.com/e/a-858/s-1486/c-705/g-2423.xgi?pkey=xbue89gtzpg16&chpcm=&chpsg=&chpcr=&chpck=&rand=' + Math.round(Math.random(99999) * 100000) + '&chpth=';
```

```html
<img id="pixel-img" src='http://h.nexac.com/e/a-858/s-1486/c-705/g-2423.xgi?pkey=xbue89gtzpg16&chpcm=&chpsg=&chpcr=&chpck=&rand=INSERT_CACHEBUSTER&chpth=' width='1' height='1' border='0'>
```

Comment: Fun fact: once you add an ID you can reference the image using `document.images['pixel-img']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use also regular expression to substitute the value.

```
var src = $("img").prop( "src" );
src = src.replace( /(.+)(rand=)(.+)(&)(.+)/, "$1rand="+rndVal+"&$5");
$("img").prop( "src", src );
```

When you use regular expression, every word between `(` `)` can accessed using `$i` where `i` is the i-th position.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYarjN

Comment: The question is not tagged `jQuery`.